# Microphones for live Interview in cheaper

Tags: microphone, audio-recording, recording, live

We are doing some question/answers in live with public,so we need suggestion which microphone will be good for us,

We found one on ebay.in on following link:

http://www.ebay.in/itm/14-37-Pro-Video-Camera-DSLR-Camcorder-Microphone-for-Canon-Nikon-Sony-Panasonic-/322336286158?hash=item4b0cbd65ce:g:EIkAAOSwXeJYM9hy

Our budget is less than 5000(Inr) ($70).

Comment: Not enough information to make any kind of useful response. How is the microphone to be used? on camera or handheld? wired or wireless?

Comment: for that price i would contemplate hiring a decent mic for a day or two

Answer (score 1):

That is one possible solution.  Whether it is good for your application depends on the environment and how it will be used.  If you expect to just fix it to the top of the camera, don't expect very good speech recording. Especially if you are using it in a noisy area.

Comment: We'll hold it in hand,

Comment: It will probably work OK. The directional properties of low-price mics is a frequent place of compromise and deficiency, so you may need to keep it rather close to the subject's mouth in high-noise conditions.  Remember that it is VERY IMPORTANT for either the camera operator or the interviewer to be wearing a good pair of monitor headphones so they can HEAR what they are doing!!!  Something that blocks ambient noise, but NOT "noise cancelling" headphones.